# How can I reset my Baxi Combi Duo-Tec HE boiler after a gas supply fault error?

Tags: plumbing, heating, boiler, hot-water

My boiler is giving me some real problems, for whatever reason, it's not resetting as it should. I ran out of gas last night and since ice put some on and tried to reset, it still thinks there is a gas supply fault. The error code is E133, this is normally quite easy to reset and the boiler works as normal, but after trying to reset it a million times I'm still having no luck. I know the gas is working because we have a gas cooker and that's fine. Also, whilst trying to reset the boiler, the switch has now moved default starting position from the top to the left? If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the switch has actually seized, all that was required was the switch to be replaced at the cost of £8.00.